# Создание фикстур

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, юнит-тесты, django-orm

Всем привет. Мне требуется создать фикстуры для тестирование своего приложения. А данных в базе очень много и я бы хотел выбрать определенное кол-во записей каждой модели.

Я понимаю что возможно создать свой менеджер в котором сделать срез, вот только это ломает сайт, так как нельзя использовать QuerySet API на срезе и в итоге я получаю ошибку

db_manager.py

```
from django.db import models


class DumpManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().order_by("-id")[:100]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from db_manager import DumpManager


class MyModel(models.Model)
    objects = DumpManager()
```

`AssertionError: Cannot reorder a query once a slice has been taken.`

Да и не совсем этот способ мне подходит так как моделей очень много и прописывать каждой модели менеджер это трудоемкая задача.

Как еще я могу выбрать определенное кол-во записей?

Comment: Что-то я вообще не понял сути проблемы. Что мешает сделать самый обыкновенный запрос `MyModel.objects.all()[:100]`, зачем трогать queryset и зачем создавать manager?

Comment: Потому что я фикстуры создаю через manage.py dumpdata. А можно иначе?

Comment: Можно открыть Блокнот и написать все фикстуры руками :) Можно сделать полный дамп, а потом руками в том же Блокноте стереть лишнее. Можно взять модуль django.core.serializers и запихнуть в него тот самый queryset, который я написал в первом комментарии. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580018/how-can-i-make-a-fixture-out-of-queryset-in-django

Comment: К сожалению это не решение.

Comment: Почему не решение? Чем django.core.serializers не подошёл?

Comment: Моделей много. Я думаю будет интереснее взять код dumpdata и адаптировать как мне надо. Приложу код решения как сделаю.

Comment: Ну вроде не должно быть проблемой перебрать все модели в цикле независимо от их количества

Comment: Ну так дампдата делает тоже самое. Зачем делать то что уже готово?)

Answer (score 3):

На мой взгляд, лучший способ создания фикстур - фабрики, неплохую реализация - [factory_boy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#).

Вот пример фабрики пользователя в `Django`:

```
from typing import Any, Sequence

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from factory import DjangoModelFactory, Faker, post_generation


class UserFactory(DjangoModelFactory):

    username = Faker("user_name")
    email = Faker("email")
    name = Faker("name")

    @post_generation
    def password(self, create: bool, extracted: Sequence[Any], **kwargs):
        password = Faker(
            "password",
            length=42,
            special_chars=True,
            digits=True,
            upper_case=True,
            lower_case=True,
        ).generate(extra_kwargs={})
        self.set_password(password)

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        django_get_or_create = ["username"]
```

Создать пользователя:

```
user = UserFactory()
```

Создать несколько пользователей:

```
users = UserFactory.create_batch()
```